# Laravel-mix output path is outputting two different wrong paths for both js and sass

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

I have a weird issue with Laravel-Mix, whenever I try to mix `sass` or `js`, they end up in a completely wrong and different directories, for example:

Here's my webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

when I run `npm run dev`, this is what I end up with these files in these paths:

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 8073ms                                                                                                                                                  08:32:45
                  Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
/vagrant/pirlanta/public/vagrant/pirlanta/public/js/app.js  1.38 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /vagrant/pirlanta/public/vagrant/pirlanta/public/js/app
                    ../../../vagrant/pirlanta//css/app.css   198 kB    0, 0  [emitted]         /vagrant/pirlanta/public/vagrant/pirlanta/public/js/app, /vagrant/pirlanta/public/vagrant/pirlanta/public/js/app
```

**One thing worth mentioning**, whenever the css is compiling, I **CANNOT** make it go inside the **public** folder, for some reason, it omits the word 'public' from the path every time, you can check that in the output above, `'../vagrant/pirlanta//css/app.css'`, there should've been 'public' between those '//', idk why it gets omitted...

Another thing actually, this Laravel app is running in a VM, so I had to make a few changes because the node_modules directory is symlinked, between`'/home/vagrant/pirlanta/node_modules'` and `'/vagrant/pirlanta/node_modules/'`.

Because I have a Windows host machine I can't install node_modules normally, I must symlink it, anyway that lead to some **unexpected behavior**, Mix was trying to read the webpack.mix file from `'/home/vagrant/pirlanta'` while the root of the project is `'/vagrant/pirlanta/'` and that's where the actual webpack.mix file exists, so I had to do some changes first:

Inside `'node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Paths.js'` I changed the `mix()` function like this:

```
 mix() {
        return this.root(
            argv.env && argv.env.mixfile ? argv.env.mixfile : '/vagrant/pirlanta/webpack.mix'
        );
```

To have it reflect the correct webpack.mix file.

I really don't know why would mix output the files to different paths, I am almost positive that this is caused by the constructor in the `Paths.js` file mentioned above, but I cannot confirm that, and I really don't know how can I fix this, I cannot get both files to compile in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution to my problem by pure luck, I will try to break what I did into steps,

**First:**
I edited `node_modules/laravel-mix/src/index.js` and removed this function
entirely:

```
if (Mix.sees('laravel')) {
    Config.publicPath = 'public';
}
```

Once I did that, my css files were able to compile inside the public folder normally, the compiling path finally **saw** the word public and I ended up with this path:

```
../../../vagrant/pirlanta/public/css/app.css
```

Which was exactly what I needed, so here's a problem **solved**.

**Second:**

I edited `node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Paths.js` and changed the
constructor like this:

```
constructor() {
        if (argv['$0'].includes('ava')) {
            this.rootPath = path.resolve('', '');
        } else {
            this.rootPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../');
        }
    }
```

Tbh I don't exactly know what I did there, but it worked, I edited the first query of the
if statement.

Once I did that, my js started compiling into its normal path inside the public folder at `/public/js/app.js`.

So now both of my problems were **solved**.

And my webpack.mix.js file looks like this as of the moment with everything working:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', '/public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', '/vagrant/pirlanta/public/css');
```

That's it, It's worth noting that this operation took me almost two full days to get it to work, I thought I should document the answer here may it help someone, thanks.

Comment: The only problem with this is it will break the second you do npm install or update again.

Comment: Yeah, we need a solution that doesn't involve hacking the node_module files.